# How to use Find a string from a column and then use that to vlookup - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with strings COL A (image names), I have a column of URLs COL B and I have a column of strings (SKU) COL C that I want to look up.
The image names have a url associated to it.
The SKUs are not in any particular order.

As follows

```
A (Image names)              |B (URL)      |C (SKU)
-----------------------------|-------------|--------
ABC0001.jpg                  |test.com/123 |XYZ0105
Walk in the park XYZ0105.jpg |test.com/456 |RST0245
Over-the-moon-RST0245.jpg .  |test.com/567 |ABC0001
```

All the images names have the SKU in it, but in some format or the other.

How do I use the SKU in Col C to find the SKU within the image name and lookup the URL against the image name?

So in the above example the URL for SKU **ABC0001** would be **test.com/123**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your sample data in a sheet named List. You don't need SKU. Then on another sheet enter the SKU to search for in A2 and enter this query in B2.

```
=query(List!A2:B,"Select B where A contains '"& A2 &"'")
```

The URL will be returned.

Comment: Thank you so very much! I've been racking my trying to figure this out.

Comment: Great and simple solution! The question that bugs me - is it possible to improve this formula to return all URLs for every SKU. One formula in only one cell. Query (Filter, Index, etc) and Arrayformula don't work. So...

Comment: I've used this in the following manner.
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"URL",query(List!A:B,"Select B where A contains '"& index(SPLIT(D:D,"-"),0,2) &"'")))

And it doesn't query in this case it just lists all the items in List - Col B, the array formula being used in the  E1 and in Column D are SKUs pre-ended as such 70008-ABC0001. However if I just use the index/split in the arrayformula it works fine, if I use the formula as 
query(List!A:B,"Select B where A contains '"& index(SPLIT(D2,"-"),0,2) &"'") and so on it works fine.

Any idea on how I can make the it work in an arrayformula?